# URL rewriting with Apache .htaccess with two matches

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry about this question - I know this is asked a lot, but this case is a little more distinct (for me at least).

I have the following content in my current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This rewrites all URLs that are from `index.php` and have the mode parameter to a simply URL where the `mode`'s content becomes the main part of the URL, like this:

```
http://someurl.com/index.php?mode=mymode

Becomes:

http://someurl.com/mymode
```

This is exactly what I need. But I also need to extend this and be able to achieve the same effect with another file of mine named `user.php`. The case is almost the same:

```
http://someurl.com/user.php?action=hello

Becomes: 

http://someurl.com/hello
```

I have no idea how to achieve the second part without conflincting with the first one.

I'm kinda stuck on this one.

Comment: You can't have `/mymode` going to `/index.php?mode=mymode` and `/hello` going to `/user.php?action=hello` since both pretty URLs are following same structure. You can have `/user/hello` for `/user.php?action=hello` if you want.

Comment: Yes please. I would appreciate if you showed me how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
# new rules for /user.php?action=hello
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]

# existing rule for /index.php?mode=mymode
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**PS:** Also better to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than arelative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.